# create single query to fetch data from tables as seperate rows

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

i am thinking if there is a better way to query product, product options and product option choices from database

my database structure is like:

```
product table (product_id, product_name)
product_options table (option_id, option_name, product_id)
product_optionChoices (Choice_id, choice_name, Option_id)
```

i want a single query that return all product and options in seperate rows like:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| product_id | product_name | option_id | option_name | choiceId | choice_name |
| 1          | shoes        |           |             |          |             |
| 1          |              | 1         | choose color|          |             |
|            |              | 1         |             | 1        | red         |
|            |              | 1         |             | 2        | blue        |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

right now i am using 3 sepearte queries to get product, product option and product_optionChoices and appending the query together using QueryAddRow in coldfusion.

Thanks

Comment: MySQL or sql-server? That are two very different thinks. Better than which way?

Comment: i need in both.. if i can get idea on how to do it in either mysql or mssql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Maybe this solution helps you even if i don't like it.**
This returns exactly what you want (UPDATED).

```
SELECT  p.product_id, p.product_name, '' as option_id, '' as option_name, ''  as choiceId, '' as choice_name FROM `product` p
UNION ALL
SELECT  pr.product_id as product_id, '' as product_name, o.option_id, o.option_name, '' as choiceId, '' as choice_name FROM `product_options` o
INNER JOIN product pr
ON pr.product_id = o.product_id
UNION ALL
SELECT  '' as product_id, '' as product_name, op.option_id as option_id, '' as option_name, c.choice_Id, c.choice_name FROM `product_optionChoices` c
INNER JOIN product_options op
ON op.option_id = c.option_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for SQL Server

```
SELECT P.product_id, P.product_name, PO.option_id, PO.option_name, POC.choiceId, POC.choice_name
FROM product P LEFT OUTER JOIN product_options PO on P.product_id = PO.product_id
               LEFT OUTER JOIN product_optionChoices POC on POC.option_id = PO.Option_id
```

Comment: This is not returning me product, product_option and choices in seperate rows..?